# Why are my cmdlets imported, exported and then imported again?

Tags: c#, powershell

I've got a binary PowerShell module with a .psd1 file and .psm1 file. (Why? Cmdlet aliases and custom type accelerators and I can't find out how to do these in C# for the life of me.)

Now the module imports and works as expected, but when I check verbose input in PowerShell. I'm seeing something odd:

```
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\path\to\module\Module.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\path\to\module\Module.dll'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet1'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet2'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet3'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet4'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet5'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet6'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Cmdlet1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Cmdlet2'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Cmdlet3'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Cmdlet4'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Cmdlet5'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Cmdlet6'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet1'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet2'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet3'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet4'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet5'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Cmdlet6'.
```

What's causing this, and do I have anything to worry about?

**Psm1 File**

```
$Accelerators = [PSObject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators');

# Create accelerators for this module.
$Accelerators::Add('Obj1', 'Company.PowerShell.Module.Object1');
$Accelerators::Add('Obj2', 'Company.PowerShell.Module.Object2');
$Accelerators::Add('Obj3', 'Company.PowerShell.Module.Object3');
...

Set-Alias -Name c1 -Value Cmdlet1
Set-Alias -Name c2 -Value Cmdlet2
...
```

**Psd1 file**

```
@{
    ModuleToProcess = 'Module.psm1'
    NestedModules   = 'Module.dll'
    ModuleVersion = '1.0.0.0'
    GUID = 'SOME-GUID-VALUE-HERE'
    Author = 'Me'
    CompanyName = 'Company'
    Copyright = '(c) 2016 Company. All rights reserved.'
    Description = 'Module description here.'
    PowerShellVersion = '4.0'
    DotNetFrameworkVersion = '4.5'
    CLRVersion = '4.0'
    ProcessorArchitecture = 'Amd64'
    PrivateData = @{
        Server = 'SOME\SQLSERVERINSTANCE'
        Database = 'DatabaseName'
        Domain = 'DOMAINNAME'
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the module loaded? Is it installed in PSModulePath? Could be that it's loading the module twice. Did you check this : similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923792/import-module-verbose-output-implies-module-is-loaded-twice

Comment: It's not in the module path as far as I can see. It's being loaded from the debug directory of a Visual Studio build.

Comment: Regarding the linked question. I don't have any subfolders in the debug folder. I have all the .dll's, .psm1, psd1 and pdb file in a single directory.

Comment: IMHO, it is because you first import .dll into your module, then you import your module into global state.

Comment: @PetSerAl, how should I be importing it then? Or is it normal behaviour to see something being imported twice?

Comment: Personally, I do not see any problem in that. I just try `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Security -Verbose` on my PC and have seen exactly same behavior.

Comment: Same here, normal behaviour then I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to answer your exact question - you have nothing to worry about, that is normal behavior.

PowerShell can load a dll or psm1 as a module, so commands are exported from those types of modules any time they are loaded.

A psd1 is also a module, but it can't define any commands by itself, it relies on commands being defined in another module like a dll or psm1.

So, when loading a module manifest (psd1), the root module or nested modules are loaded, exporting the command they export. The module manifest then re-exports the commands as specified by the module manifest. Note this list can limit what is actually exported by the dll/psm1.

Now, you are looking for a way to avoid the need for a psm1+dll.

You can define aliases in your binary module with the Alias attribute, the same attribute that is used to define parameter aliases. This capability was added in V4.

If you require V3, you can create a type that implements this interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.imoduleassemblyinitializer.onimport(v=vs.85).aspx, if you poke around with Reflector, you can find an example that uses this way to define alias in Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.dll, class Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.CimCmdletsAssemblyInitializer.

Comment: Well that's one half of the problem solved, what do I do about Type Accelerators?

Comment: If you are using V5, I'd say do nothing, 'using namespace' makes accelerators unnecessary.

Comment: Otherwise, you'd add the C# equivalent of the PowerShell you have to create an accelerator in your IModuleAssemblyInitializer implementation.

Comment: It's V4 in this case, but I'll have a look on MSDN for that interface.